# PHP checkdate() seems to allow decimals

Tags: php

So today I come across a little anomaly today with `checkdate()`

Basically, it allows decimals

`checkdate(2,21.5,2000); //returns TRUE
 checkdate(2.345,28.345,1988.3453); //returns TRUE`

is that normal? Because I was hoping `checkdate()` would also check that the entered values are integers rather than decimals ... What makes it more annoying is that `is_int()` doesn't work with strings

Comment: I am pretty sure it just truncates the anything after the decimal

Comment: checkdate is converting the decimals to integer automatically. is_int() does work with strings. Please refer to the manual, particularly the example - http://php.net/is_int#refsect1-function.is-int-examples

Comment: `checkdate` works with `long`s internally, I am sure it just casts float to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why doesn't it work?

[`checkdate()`](http://php.net/checkdate) function doesn't check if the arguments passed to it are valid integers. If they're not, it just casts it into an integer, as if [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) were applied. So, this is how your date values look like when `checkdate()`  processes them:

```
$a = array(2,21.5,2000);
$b = array(2.345,28.345,1988.3453);

print_r(array_map('intval', $a));
print_r(array_map('intval', $b));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 2000
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 28
    [2] => 1988
)
```

As you can see, everything after the decimal place has been trimmed off.

### Alternative solution

As an alternative to `checkdate()`, you can use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class to do the validation. It is very robust and can handle a wide range of dates (function by [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/), from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205%5D)):

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with string input you can use a regular expression to check for formatting issues and `checkdate` for validation.

```
function is_valid_date($date) {
   // does it look like a date?
    if (preg_match("/^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$/", $date, $matches)) {
        // is it a valid date?
        return checkdate($matches[1], $matches[2], $matches[3]);
    }
    return false;
}
var_dump(is_valid_date("01-01-1970")); // true
var_dump(is_valid_date("20-20-1970")); // false
var_dump(is_valid_date("1.6-4.3-12345")); // false
```